# How to add table name into dynamic query in execute immediate?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, plsql, execute-immediate

I'm confused, because I don't know how to use variable as string in `execute immediate` clause.

```
declare
  variable1 varchar2(30):
  cur sys_refcursor;
begin
  open cur for
    select tablename from table1;

  loop
    fetch cur into variable1;
    exit when cur %notfound;

    execute immediate 'select count(*)
                         into variable1
                         from user_tables
                        where table_name =''' || variable1 || '''';
  end loop;

  close cur;

end;
```

Here `variable1` is a table name. There should be a string value. How to do that? Still got an error.

Comment: Note that there is no reason (and no benefit) to using dynamic SQL at all here.  If this is the real problem, use static SQL.  And put counts in an `integer` or `number` variable, not into a `varchar2(30)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute immediate statement should look like this:

```
execute immediate 'select count(*) from user_tables where table_name ='''||variable1||'''' into variable1;
```

with the into xxx after the query.

Comment: Better use `execute immediate 'select count(*) from user_tables where table_name = :var1' into variable1 USING variable1;`